# Custom wp-content and upload directory

Tags: customization

I setup a single directory/ multiple sites WordPress Setup.  And it worked as well. For some time. It still works but for one problem. The image upload doesn't work properly.

I'll explain.

Setup:-
1. One master directory containing full WordPress installation.
2. One directory for client site - lets say client1.
 Here is the full folder structure within public_html

```
-MasterDirectory
-client1
    -wordpress -> MasterDirectory/wordpress
    -wp-config.php
    -wp-content
         -plugins -> MasterDirectory/wordpress/wp-content/plugins
         -themes -> MasterDirectory/wordpress/wp-content/themes
         -uploads
```

3. Master installation wp-config.php edited to only contain

```
$site_directory =  dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $site_directory . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/wp-content');

// load site-specific configurations
require_once dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/wp-config.php';
```

I took advice from [here](https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/updated-wordpress-multitenancy/).

4. I created client1/wp-config.php and updated it correctly.
5. Fired up wordpress and it worked smoothly.
6. Now when I upload image, it gets uploaded correctly to client1/wp-content/uploads/2017.... However, when I try to load it, it results in 404. Even in media library, no thumbnails are visible (missing images). Funnily, when I click on Edit Image button, the image is visible.

Attempted Debugging Till now-
7. Server log shows, that it is trying to look for the image in MasterDirectory/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/.... instead of client1/wp-content/uploads/2017/....
8. I tested to check what are the wordpress values by checking the contents of `wp_upload_dir();`.  All expected values are returned.

```
path=public_html/client1/wp-content/uploads/2017/01 
url=https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01
subdir=/2017/01 </br>basedir=public_html/client1/wp-content/uploads
baseurl=https://example.com/wp-content/uploads 
error=
```

I have spent the entire sunday trying to figure out the anomaly but can't find the problem as to why is server looking for image in MasterDirectory when the wordpress variables/ constants are correctly set.

Site is using default twentyseventeen theme through child theme. No plugins activated whatsoever, although quite a few are placed in plugins folder.  Theme

The question is lengthy, as I tried to explain the maximum.

Thanks for your time people.

Comment: this sounds like a problem in the configuration of your web server What are your virtual host setting?

Comment: I have tried the location block to serve content from client directory like:

 `location /wp-content {
  alias /path/to/public_html/deflink/wp-content;
 }`
 
I have also tried `root` instead of `alias`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't win them, Join Them!

So after a little (and then some more) flipped the entire idea. Earlier, I was trying to move the Uploads directory to another place. But the setup was reluctant in doing so, always making the uploads to master directory. So this is where I 'joined' WordPress behaviour.

I made a directory within ->`public_html/MasterDirectory/wordpress/wp-content/client1/`.
Another directory in client1 directory ->`public_html/client1/uploads`.
Then symlinked `public_html/client1/uploads` to `public_html/MasterDirectory/wordpress/wp-content/client1/`

So while the WordPress uploads to symlinked directory on Master Directory/../../uploads, it actually gets to client1/.././uploads.

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another line in wp-config.php

```
define('UPLOADS', '$site_directory . '/wp-content/uploads');
```

You need to add this before `require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);`

Comment: This creates subdirectory within master directory/wordpress/wp-content/public_html/client1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads.....